# Distribution cost of Acroform which is reader-enabled using Acrobat

Tags: adobe, itext

we have prepared Acroforms using iText which is save restricted in default in Adobe reader, to  enable save option, we used Adobe Acrobat. Now to distribute this editable pdfs, do we need to incur distribution cost of editable pdfs along with the licensing cost of adobe acrobat?